# WPF Styles Button MouseOver Question

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I am trying to make a simple mouseover effect on a button, It does change the color when mouse is over but the color is immediately changed to the default button background... how can I override this behavior?

this is my code:

```
Style myBtnStyle = new Style();
Trigger bla = new Trigger() { Property = IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true };
bla.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Black));
myBtnStyle.Triggers.Add(bla);
button2.Style = myBtnStyle;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/46ec6902-a498-455a-b9e1-95269f888e79/), that fancy animation is built into and to remove it, you're going to need to override the `ControlTemplate` for your `Button`. Fortunately, that isn't too hard. I used [this post](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2007/07/creating-custom-wpf-button-template-in.html) as source material and came up with the following `Style` that gives you the idea.

```xml
<Style x:Key="MouseOverButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Style x:Key="ShadowStyle">
                        <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="LightGray" />
                    </Style>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Border Name="border" BorderThickness="1" Padding="4,2" BorderBrush="DarkGray" CornerRadius="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid >
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="contentShadow" Style="{StaticResource ShadowStyle}">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform X="1.0" Y="1.0" />
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="content"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Beige" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**Update:**
If you're dead set on applying the `Style` in code and you don't want to use a `ResourceDictionary` (probably the better way to do it), you can load the `Style` dynamically using `XamlReader.Load`:

```xml
            const string xaml = @"
<Style xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
       xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
       TargetType='Button'>
    <Setter Property='Template'>
        <!--- Omitted For Clarity --->
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property='IsMouseOver' Value='True'>
            <Setter Property='Background' Value='Beige' />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>";
            var encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(xaml);
            var style = (Style)XamlReader.Load(new MemoryStream(bytes));
            Button1.Style = style;
```

Comment: You could put the style in a resource dictionary and then pull it out when needed to apply to your button.

Comment: When the Style Triggers on "IsMouseOver", the previously defined Button.Background.ImageBrush disappears, though the only Style in the Trigger is for Opacity. Any Suggestions what I'm missing? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Overriding the ButtonChrome theme would be easier.

Create a template and remove the RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"

```
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome x:Name="Chrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"RenderPressed="{TemplateBinding IsPressed}" RenderDefaulted="{TemplateBinding Button.IsDefaulted}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ButtonChrome>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="RenderDefaulted" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="RenderPressed" TargetName="Chrome" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFADADAD"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And then add your own handling of mouseover

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF3E8D5" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFF49B03" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

That should solve it! :)

Comment: You should mention how to register Microsoft_Windows_Themes, add `xmlns:themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"` and Add Reference `PresentationFramework.Aero` to project.