# wpf button trigger doesnt work as it should

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple button. I want to switch it's template(or style ...)when it is being preesed.

I want to change from this

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Click="Button_Click"
            DataContext="{Binding}"
            Height="65" Width="79"
            Background="Black"
            Content="{Binding Path=CardWasFounded}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

to this :

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Click="Button_Click"
            DataContext="{Binding}"
            Height="65" Width="79"
            Background="{Binding Path=ButtonColor}"
            Content="{Binding Path=CardWasFounded}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT**

After i have done

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Name="btn"
            Click="Button_Click"
            DataContext="{Binding}"
            Height="65" Width="79"
            Background="Black"/>

     <DataTemplate.Triggers>
         <Trigger SourceName="btn" Property="IsMouseCaptured" Value="True" >
             <Setter TargetName="btn" Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                           <!--"{Binding Path=ButtonColor}"-->
         </Trigger>
     </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

It's still doesn't work I think it's because the .net default or something when the mouse is over the button its get's the blue defult color insted of my green or my binding ...

My goal its when its clicked to hook up a binding to color and a storyboard 
can someone help me achive it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this effect with a trigger. You could set a trigger that changes the Background property to your desired value when the button's IsPressed property (or some similar property) equals true.

For more information, take a look at:
 http://en.csharp-online.net/WPF_Styles_and_Control_Templates%E2%80%94Property_Triggers

Comment: Hum...I wonder if this answer would help you in disabling the default animation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687271/wpf-styles-button-mouseover-question